# Filter includes_url()  PHP function (to change wp-includes URL)

Tags: php, wordpress

[`includes_url()`](http://queryposts.com/function/includes_url/) is a function that retrieves the url to the includes directory in WordPress, the output of which by default looks like `http://example.com/wp-includes/`.

The function's [code from the core](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/3.4/wp-includes/link-template.php#L1993):

```
function includes_url($path = '') {
    $url = site_url() . '/' . WPINC . '/';

    if ( !empty($path) && is_string($path) && strpos($path, '..') === false )
        $url .= ltrim($path, '/');

    return apply_filters('includes_url', $url, $path);
}
```

How do I replace the function it with my own (using functions.php)? Essentially, I want to change the second line to this — `$url = 'http://static-content.com/' . WPINC . '/';`

Answer (score 4):

There is a filter you can make use of with [`add_filter`](http://queryposts.com/function/add_filter/) to make the existing function return what *you* want:

```
$callback = function($url, $path) {
    $url = 'http://static-content.com/' . WPINC . '/';

    if ( !empty($path) && is_string($path) && strpos($path, '..') === false )
        $url .= ltrim($path, '/');

    return $url;
};

add_filter('includes_url', $callback, 10, 2);
```

*Edit:* PHP 5.2 version:

```
function includes_url_static($url, $path) {
    $url = 'http://static-content.com/' . WPINC . '/';

    if ( !empty($path) && is_string($path) && strpos($path, '..') === false )
        $url .= ltrim($path, '/');

    return $url;
}

$callback = 'includes_url_static';

add_filter('includes_url', $callback, 10, 2);
```

Comment: Is the first line correct? I am getting this error when I add the code: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION in /home/xxxx/public_html/wp-content/themes/bbbb/functions.php on line 657`

Comment: That's because your PHP version is not compatible. You need to define the function first, and then add it's name as string instead. I added an example about that.

Comment: That made wordpress famous somehow. Having a hashtable full of callbacks.

Comment: @AahanKrish: No you are not. You are below PHP 5.3. Take it for granted, otherwise you would not have the parse error. I added you a PHP 5.2 version

Comment: @hakre Okay, my host isn't updating my stuff. But this time, I've another error: `Warning: Missing argument 2 for includes_url_static() in /home/xxxx/public_html/wp-content/themes/bbbb/functions.php on line 657`

Comment: @hakre Changed first line to `function includes_url_static($url, $path = '') {` and I see no more errors. But the source still shows the same URLs. Not `http://static-content.com/wp-includes/` -- weird!

Comment: Okay, you might have a conflict with some other plugin. That's not so easy to explain. Inside the function you can do a `var_dump($GLOBALS['wp_filter']['includes_url']);` to get a list of all callbacks registered on the filter. Maybe this helps you to find the culprit.

Comment: Other portions of your site might use other function btw to retrieve the URL, so you should verify by debugging how the URLs are being created. I can highly suggest xdebug for that and then stepping though. Everything else only takes needles time with wordpress.

Comment: @AahanKrish: Your filter is called two times. It's the only filter there. I edited the answer because of the first issue which needs additional parameters. Should not trigger your problem, however should remove the cause, not the symptom. Also take a look where the include URL is *really*  generated for your output.

Comment: @hakre Sorry, I just tried the revised code. It's not doing anything. Everyone's told me not to touch wp-includes, and it's proving to be true. I think I should resort to simple de-register and enqueue functions. Thanks a lot for your time. :)

Comment: @hakre And I could not follow some of your instructions like `Also take a look where the include URL is really generated for your output.` because I am learning PHP (just beginning), and I don't really know what you meant, and even if I did there's very little I can do. Sorry about that.

Comment: Okay, that's actually not really easy for a beginner I assume. Don't you have any friend or so you can go through that in front of the same computer together?

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to create your own function and have it call `includes_url()` and alter it.

```
function custom_includes_url($path = '') {
  $url = includes_url($path);

  return str_replace(site_url(), 'http://static-content.com', $url);
}
```

But you'd have to invoke `custom_includes_url()` everywhere.

Comment: Unfortunately every plugin uses `includes_url()` so I need to make use of the filter in the function to modify it to my needs. The answer would have been an option if the problem was only with my theme. But thanks a lot for trying to help. :)